# Remove Windows boot loader

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.04, bootloader

I recently changed from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 10.04 as my default OS.

I formatted the hard drive with Windows 7 on it, but it still shows the boot loader at startup.

How do I remove the Windows 7 bootloader?

Comment: Installing Ubuntu should make grub the default loader. Have you disabled it, or took any other steps?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just showing the Windows entry on GRUB?  GRUB looks something like http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/1/12/20090214001220!GRUB_screenshot.png

Comment: @Tom: Make sure that you click the checkmark next to an answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo grub-update`

Comment: There is no `grub-update` command. May be you meant `update-grub`. Actually this command won't remove Windows 7 or 8 loader it simply scans and updates the boot list.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Grub or Grub2 and you have to edit menu.lst in case of grub and grub.cfg in case of grub2 for windows selection according to the partition.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to get grub to rescan to allow it to find / not find any operating systems that have been added / removed since grub was installed.
The command is update-grub, and there is a [Ubuntu Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GrubHowto) on using Grub that you might find useful.